# Change Selectize load url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

```
selectize({
        valueField: 'Id',
        labelField: 'Name',
        searchField: 'Name',
        load: function (query, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/some_url/params?SOME_ID=4&keyword=' + encodeURIComponent(query),
                success: function (response) {}
            });
        }
    });
```

in the above snippet, is it possible to change the value of SOME_ID in request params based on some event
without destroying are re initializing the whole input ?
thanks in advance

the only solution i found was to destroy and re initialize the input, but am looking for a better approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing the value in a suitably scoped variable.

Since the `load` function is called for each search, it will be evaluated correctly.

For example

```js
const selectizeQueryParams = {
  SOME_ID: 4, // initial value
};

document.addEventListener('some-event', (e) => {
  selectizeQueryParams.SOME_ID = 'newValue';
});

// ...

selectize({
  valueField: 'Id',
  labelField: 'Name',
  searchField: 'Name',
  load: function (keyword, callback) {
    $.get('/some_url/params', {
      ...selectizeQueryParams,
      keyword, //  jQuery automatically encodes params when passed as an object
    }).done(function (response) {});
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks for this idea, it really saved me a headache